# How to follow a "page auto-redirection" to get the response code?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde, rim-4.5, blackberry-os-v4.5

I use the following code to get the returned response code of an aspx page

```
HttpConnection connection 
     = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://company.com/temp1.aspx" 
                                       + ";deviceside=true");
connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.HEADER_CONNECTION, "close");
connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, "0");
int resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

It works fine. 
But what if the link "http://company.com/temp1.aspx" auto-redirects to another page;  assume "http://noncompany.com/temp2.aspx" ? 
How can i get the response code which is returned from the second link (the one which the first link redirected to) ? 
Is there something like "follow redirection" to get the new response of the page whom was auto-redirected to ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution,
Here it is for those who are interested:

```
int resCode;
String location = "http://company.com/temp1.aspx";
while (true) {  
     HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(location + ";deviceside=true");
     connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
     connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.HEADER_CONNECTION, "close");
     connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, "0");
     resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
     if( resCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_TEMP_REDIRECT
          || resCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
          || resCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM ) {
          location = connection.getHeaderField("location").trim();
     } else {
          resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: You may want to replace the while(true) statement with a for loop (up to 5-10 tries or so) to prevent getting into an infinite redirect loop, which can happen sometimes with an incorrectly configured web server or proxy.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the comment. I think also there's another solution, to keep track of redirected links, by adding each new location (link) to a vector for example, and whenever a new redirection link is found, the code should first check if it exists in the vector, because if it exists there it'll cause cyclic infinite redirection. Thanks for this note.

Answer (score 3):

You need to code your HttpConnection inside a loop that follows HTTP redirections based on the response code.

The HTTP header "location" in the response is supposed to give you a new host (maybe it can be used to replace the entire URL).

`HttpConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP` and `HttpConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM` are the two response code that indicate a redirection.

Comment: Thanks Man,
I've seen your answer after posting my solution.
By the way, there exist another response code which is HttpConnection.HTTP_TEMP_REDIRECT . 
Thanks again for your reply.
I'll mark it as an answer and up.